# iphone 5c needing to send messages

Tags: iphone

Okay so I broke my iPhone and it is black, and I tried syncing it but it goes  to saying I have to put in my iphone password but I cant because the screen is black. How do I access my messages and send them, also get all my contacts back???

Answer (score -4):

if u have i coloud are itune account go and login u have all details in that

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.